# how do i make a jquery plugin

Tags: plugins, jquery, rss

I'm trying to make a jquery plugin
but it's not working what a'm i doing wrong

```
(function($){
    $.fn.rss({ 

        //pass the options variable to the function
        rss: function(options) {
            //Set the default values, use comma to separate the settings, example:
            var defaults = {
                feedUrl: ''
            }

            var options =  $.extend(defaults, options);

            return this.each(function() {
                var Setting = options;
                //code to be inserted here

$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: Setting.feedUrl,
    dataType: "xml",
    success: function(xml) {

        $(xml).find('channel').each(function(){
        $(xml).find('image').each(function(){
        var title2 = $(this).find('title').text();
        var url2   = $(this).find('link').text();
        $('<div class="title"></div>').html('<a href="'+url2+'">'+title2+'</a>').fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#title');
        });
        $(xml).find('item').each(function(){
        var title = $(this).find('title').text();
        var brief = $(this).find('description').text();
        var url  = $(this).find('link').text();
        $('<div class="items"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'"><div class="dis">'+brief+'</div></a>').fadeIn(1000).appendTo('#blab');
        });
        });
    }
});
});
        }
    });

})(jQuery)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By writing `$.fn.rss(...)`, you're *calling* a non-existent function.

You need to create a function by writing

```
$.fn.rss = function(...) { ... };
```

Comment: i gotta bot now how to i make it hover